# catkin_create_pkg failure

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin-create-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

catkin_create_package fails with the following error when I try to create a package on my new laptop:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/catkin_create_pkg", line 75, in 
main()
File "/usr/bin/catkin_create_pkg", line 63, in main
boost_comps=args.boost_comps)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package_templates.py", line 142, in _create_package_template
urls=[])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package_templates.py", line 55, in **init**
self.validate()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 244, in validate
raise InvalidPackage('\n'.join(errors))
catkin_pkg.package.InvalidPackage: Invalid email "CRA@rhutchins@todo.todo" for person "CRA@rhutchins"

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Ryan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240628/catkin_create_pkg-failure/) by [The_Mad_Geometer](https://answers.ros.org/users/23167/the_mad_geometer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-07-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the error message states (`Invalid email`) the value `CRA@rhutchins@todo.todo` is not a valid email address (it contains two at signs).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [The_Mad_Geometer](https://answers.ros.org/users/23167/the_mad_geometer/) on 2016-09-01**:
Thanks Dirk.

Your diagnosis was correct. The fix is to specify:

catkin_create_package -m rhutchins <package_name>

So, simply typing my user name without the domain preceding it fixed my problem.